# Sending JSON with escape characters such as group separators

Tags: c#, json, json.net, escaping, ascii

**Specific Question**:  How should one format characters such as group separator (0x1D) in JSON?

**Details:**
I've inherited a C# codebase that is reading some barcodes, putting them in JSON messages and sending them on their way to a service (not necessarily C# or Windows based!)

The code takes a byte array such as:

```
byte[] rawData = { 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 
                   48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 52, 29, 49,
                   48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48, 48};
```

and uses code like this to translate this byte array to a string which is put in .json:

```
string dataNew = Regex.Unescape(new string(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(rawData).ToCharArray()));
```

The relevant part of .json then looks like:

```
"Notes": [
  {
    "Id": 0,
    "Details": "Produc code: CodeType: DataMatrix, Data: 000000000000000000000000000004\u001d1000000000000000",
    "Active": true,
    "Acknowledged": false,
    "Reported": false
  }
],
```

As you can see, the `Encoding.ASCII.GetString...` treated ASCII character 29 (0x1d) a little differently.  It put in a "\u001".  If you don't put in the Regex.Unescape it puts in "\\u001".  I'm shaky on encoding and .json.  Can someone tell me:

1. What is "\u001".  Is it Microsoft specific?
2. The folks receiving this message are stating that their servers "choke" on this message.  No problems when there is no group separator.  Can a group separator be sent via .json messages?  And if so how?  If it's doable, how would you decode it with C# technologies?

Slightly more info:  The server folks say that \u001 is rendered as ^] (which indicates a non-printable character) on their end.  I could just strip the \u001 before sending the message and that might not be a bad idea.  But it occurs to me that there are other non-printable characters (CR, LF for example) where it might be good to keep that info and send it via .json.

Please excuse my vagueness.  I'm still getting familiar with this code base and these particular ideas.  I did try and find out what \u001 is but to no avail.  I could ask for a better explanation than "choke", but it would be nice to have some specific questions in mind.  If I can provide clarification or more details please let me know.

Comment: What is `rawData`?  Is it an arbitrary sequence of bytes that could have any values?  Or are they actually ASCII character values?

Comment: To my knowledge, they are bytes representing ascii character values only.  That is, I don't believe there are any characters outside 0-127 that we need to deal with.  I "sanitized" the array to have mostly 0s (ascii 48).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not `Encording.ASCII.GetString` that is inserting the `\u` escape sequence; it is the JSON serialization process (which you have not shown in your question) that is doing it, and that is perfectly normal and expected.

In [JSON](http://www.json.org), unprintable characters in a string are encoded as `\u` + four hexadecimal digits, where the digits are the Unicode (UTF-16) representation of the character.  In your output, you can see that is exactly what has happened: you have `\u001d`, which is ASCII character 29 from the original byte sequence.

Generally, to avoid problems with creating and decoding JSON, you should always use a JSON serialization library such as [JSON.Net](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json) which is designed to handle all that for you.  I'm guessing that the "server folks" you mention in your question are attempting to parse the JSON manually, and that is why they are running into trouble.  If you're doing everything correctly, you should not need to use Regexes at all to manipulate the JSON string, including using `Regex.Unescape`.

Here is a short fiddle to demonstrate: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Uy3PcM

Comment: Thanks for the response Brian. I think the \u001d is present before .json serialization as you can see from hovering over at a breakpoint.  I agree it doesn't show up if you write the string to line.  And perhaps there is a clue in that? In any case, you've given me much to think about.  Is \u001d general (or Microsoft specific).  If general, are the server guys using a library?  I will confirm on Monday, but believe they may be using Ruby on Rails. I assume there are .json libraries available for Ruby that handle \u001d, but am not sure.

Comment: And thank you very much for putting me on to dotnetfiddle.  Very impressive.  Unfortunately, you can't hover over values at breakpoints (or even have breakpoints?) as far as I can tell.  But very useful none the less.

Comment: `\u001d` is the same as `0x1D` -- it is the Group Separator character encoded with four hexadecimal digits instead of two.  It is not "Microsoft specific" at all; it is [standard ASCII](http://www.asciitable.com/) encoded as [standard JSON](http://www.json.org/).  All JSON libraries worth their salt should be able to handle the `\u` character escape notation, regardless of what language, if they are following the standard.  And yes, there are several JSON libraries available for Ruby, as shown at the bottom of the [JSON.org](http://www.json.org/) page.

Comment: You are correct that DotNetFiddle does not support breakpoints or debugging; that is why I am using Console.WriteLine to show the values of everything. If you want to step through that code in a debugger, just take it and dump it into a new Console Application project in Visual Studio. You'll need to include a reference to JSON.Net though.

Comment: Thank you very much Brian. Marking as answer.  I think I'm zeroing on the problem.  I posted a new question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40477952/losing-non-printable-ascii-character-group-separator-when-deserializing-with-j   As you can see, I'm losing the individual characters \u 0 0 1 d and it's being repaced with 29 when I deserialize a json string.